# How to force generating a warning in DartEditor

Tags: dart

I'm looking for a way to generate a warning anywhere in my code (top level, class, functions). As I'm typically having a 0 warning policy, this enables me to see where I make a change I  need to revert before commit

For example in Java, i could do this:

```
private int warning_revert_to_false;
boolean DEBUG = true;
```

and it will generate a warning (according to my settings). 
Using jslint/jshint that's easy (mixed tab/space for example), in C/C++ i can use pragma...

Basically I want the code to still compile and run and so far in Dart, I could not find a simple solution and I'm sure there is one that I have missed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following library to your program:

```
library forced;    
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class Forced {
  @deprecated
  static void warning() {

  }
}
```

Wherever you want a forced warning you can simply write:

```
Forced.warning();
```

Comment: great, thanks! i can even use it before a top level variable definition (i.e. outside the scope of a function using something like: var v = Forced.warning(); )